# Is it legal to leave a prerecorded voicemail (US law)?

Tags: tcpa

Is it legal under US law to leave a prerecorded voicemail after a cold call to a prospect? Let's say a sales development representative makes cold calls to a list of enterprise prospects. If the prospect doesn't answer and it goes to voicemail, rather than leaving a voicemail each time, the SDR leaves a prerecorded voicemail which would save significant time. From my understanding, this is legal under US law but seek clarification.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's legal, but I'm just as sure that it's not a sound marketing strategy.